# Detach Writer from System.out without closing

Tags: java, io

Some tool I have uses `Writer` as output. I want to write to `System.out`, so I created an `OutputStreamWriter` for `System.out`. My problem is that I want to do other things with the standard output of my program after I completed this task. I did not find any means to detach the writer.

Is there any common `Writer` implementation that can do that? Should I write my own `Writer`? Should I call `flush()` on my `OutputStreamWriter` and then leak it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override close and flush instead:

```
    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(System.out) {
        @Override
        public void close() {
            flush();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just `.flush()` it and let it be. It doesn't mean you'd "leak" it: the `Writer` object will get garbage collected, and the underlying stream is still in use. Nothing wrong with that.